# calculating date between two fields

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a "leave start date" and "leave end date" date picker field and a number field with leave types eg. sick, vacation etc. I have a pl/sql code that calculate the leave type field

```
declare
  leave_end_date DATE;
  leave_start_date DATE;
begin
  leave_start_date := to_date(:P6_leave_START_DATE || ' ' || :P6_leave_START_TIME, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  leave_end_date := to_date(:P6_leave_END_DATE || ' ' || :P6_leave_END_TIME, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  RETURN (leave_end_date-leave_start_date);
end;
```

and it works fine. however I want to put a "where clause" in the statement. so when I chose vacation leave and I set the date picker field it only calculate for vacation and when I chose the sick leave and set the date picker field it only calculate for sick.

Comment: What is the purpose of time portion when you are not using it in the format mask? It will only have the date, without time portion. Also, the question is unclear and incomplete. Please explain clearly the requirement with a test case.

Comment: What is your question? Which variable stores the leave type?

Comment: i have an employee leave form .. In the form there are different leave types eg , sick leave , vacation leave etc.. what i want to do is to calculate the datediff between the two date picker fields which is Leave start date and leave end date. the pl/sql above works ( i am using a setvalue dynamic action) however if i chose in the "affected items " sick leave and vacation leave i will get the datediff for the two fields when i submit the page. so in the pl sql i would like to add a where clause so when i chose vacation leave it will only give me the datediff for vacation and so on

Comment: the sick and vacation leave field is "leavetype" and the a number field and the leave start date and leave end date are date picker fields . Hope i made it a little clearer let me know, if you don't understand and i will create an account for you to see

Comment: There are two unclear things: 1) you calculate date diff and say that it is a "leave type". Date minus date gives a number. Your leave types are numbers? 2) You want to put a "where clause". It is possible to put "where clause" only into an SQL query. You have no SQL queries in question, so where do you want to put it?

Comment: ok i will try to be more clear. maybe i used the wrong word (datediff) . let me start over. I have 2 date pickers (Leave start date and leave end date), i have a leave type field which is a select list, (sick and vacation) and i have number fields to correspond with the leave types (so sick leave will have a number field under it as well as vacation). now the pl/sql above allows me to get the number between the two dates (from the picker). so if i chose todays date and tomorrow date i will get "1" and this is correct. However when i submit the page sick leave will be 1 and vacation will be 1

Comment: what i want is for when i chose the leave type for eg. sick and i chose the two dates when i submit the page i only want sick leave to be 1. Yes i know only sql has a where clause i was just drawing a reference. So from the pl/sql or any other code given can i get the desired result i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then all you need to do is to set a conditon to execute the Dynamic Action, based on a the leave-type page item value.

Comment: am doing what you said but its not working i will try again

Comment: That's great! Glad it helped.